# Parse pipe-delimited serialized strings

Tags: php, arrays, validation, deserialization

How can I correctly extract this information in php?
For example, I need information about the customer and the id.

contents
shipping_address
currency
customer
....

Thank you

```
"sessiontoken|s:32:"6450a6e3ced9cdbc38c82e51376efc0f";ClicShoppingCart|a:5:{s:8:"contents";a:1:{i:21;a:1:{s:3:"qty";i:5;}}s:14:"sub_total_cost";i:0;s:10:"total_cost";i:0;s:12:"total_weight";d:0;s:16:"shipping_address";a:2:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"265";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"73";}}language|s:2:"fr";currency|s:3:"USD";new_products_id_in_cart|i:21;cart_country_id|s:2:"73";Shop|a:1:{s:17:"NavigationHistory";a:1:{s:8:"snapshot";N;}cart_address_id|N;sendto|i:24;customer_group_id|a:1:{s:18:"customers_group_id";s:1:"0";}customer|a:8:{s:2:"id";i:11;s:10:"first_name";s:4:"XXX";s:9:"last_name";s:7:"XXXXXX";s:13:"email_address";s:21:"xxx.xxxx@xxxxxx.fr";s:9:"telephone";N;s:10:"country_id";i:38;s:7:"zone_id";i:76;s:18:"default_address_id";i:24;}cartID|s:5:"57448";billto|i:24;payment|s:21:"Payment\Desjardins\HO";comments|s:0:"";shipping|a:3:{s:2:"id";s:45:"colispostalprioritaire_colispostalprioritaire";s:5:"title";s:70:"Colis International Prioritaire (France) (Livraison vers CA : 0 Kg(s))";s:4:"cost";i:18;}coupon|s:0:"";"
```

Comment: This looks serialized.  Try `unserialize()´

Comment: `unserialize()` will not work because this is not a standard serialized string.  In fact, I've searched for a while now and can't find a whisper about a serialized data format that uses pipes like this.  Amy, is this truly a custom creation or is this format documented somewhere in some offical language?  Are you in control of it's creation?  Must it be dealt with in this form?  I have it mostly reformatted for php, but not 100%.  Can you tell us more about your input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I can't find any documentation on the web that uses pipes to designate top-level keys in the serialized data, I have to assume this is a home-grown concoction.  To make matters worse there are a few errors in what is otherwise a nearly-regular serialized data string.  This being the case, your string must be custom parsed into an array for reliable handling.

I have done that job for you.  My script will correct your sample data (no guaranteed on it being 100% effective for your other home grown strings) and convert it to an array.  From the resulting array, you can either access the elements directly by key or loop.  You can also choose to use `serialize()` to convert it into a valid serialized data string for proper future storage/handling.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91d4c7bf46ef3858736a597e4fd9f9d1476cf94f)

Code:

```
$serialstring='sessiontoken|s:32:"6450a6e3ced9cdbc38c82e51376efc0f";ClicShoppingCart|a:5:{s:8:"contents";a:1:{i:21;a:1:{s:3:"qty";i:5;}}s:14:"sub_total_cost";i:0;s:10:"total_cost";i:0;s:12:"total_weight";d:0;s:16:"shipping_address";a:2:{s:7:"zone_id";s:3:"265";s:10:"country_id";s:2:"73";}}language|s:2:"fr";currency|s:3:"USD";new_products_id_in_cart|i:21;cart_country_id|s:2:"73";Shop|a:1:{s:17:"NavigationHistory";a:1:{s:8:"snapshot";N;}cart_address_id|N;sendto|i:24;customer_group_id|a:1:{s:18:"customers_group_id";s:1:"0";}customer|a:8:{s:2:"id";i:11;s:10:"first_name";s:4:"XXX";s:9:"last_name";s:7:"XXXXXX";s:13:"email_address";s:21:"xxx.xxxx@xxxxxx.fr";s:9:"telephone";N;s:10:"country_id";i:38;s:7:"zone_id";i:76;s:18:"default_address_id";i:24;}cartID|s:5:"57448";billto|i:24;payment|s:21:"Payment\Desjardins\HO";comments|s:0:"";shipping|a:3:{s:2:"id";s:45:"colispostalprioritaire_colispostalprioritaire";s:5:"title";s:70:"Colis International Prioritaire (France) (Livraison vers CA : 0 Kg(s))";s:4:"cost";i:18;}coupon|s:0:""';
//var_export(unserialize($serialstring));  this fails because the string has errors in it

if(preg_match_all('/(\w+)\|(.*?)(?=(\w+)\||$)/',$serialstring,$matches)){
    foreach($matches[1] as $i=>$k){
        $v=$matches[2][$i];  // post-pipe group
        if(preg_match_all('/s:(\d+):"([^"]*?)"/',$v,$matches2)){ // capture string lengths and values
            foreach($matches2[1] as $i=>$len){
                if(($newlen=strlen($matches2[2][$i]))!=$len){  // if bad string length count, fix it
                    $v=str_replace("s:{$len}:\"{$matches2[2][$i]}\"","s:{$newlen}:\"{$matches2[2][$i]}\"",$v);
                }
            }
        }
        if(substr_count($v,"{")>substr_count($v,"}")){ // if insufficient closing curly brackets, fix it
            $v.=str_repeat("}",substr_count($v,"{")-substr_count($v,"}"));
        }
        if(!in_array(substr($v,-1),[";","}"])){
            $v.=";"; // append semicolon where not ending in } or ;
        }
        $result[$k]=unserialize($v);
    }
}
var_export($result);  // this is the array
echo "\n\n";
echo serialize($result);  // this is the valid serialized data string
```